Solana mainnet RPC full sync issue
We are syncing a Solana mainnet RPC full node. However, when we check the health status, the gap in the number of blocks behind is fluctuating — sometimes increasing and sometimes decreasing. Do you have any advice on this?

We have 

    755 RAM
    CPU op-mode(s):                       32-bit, 64-bit
    CPU(s):                               64
    On-line CPU(s) list:                  0-63
    CPU family:                           25
    CPU max MHz:                          3799.0720
    CPU min MHz:                          1500.0000
    NUMA node0 CPU(s):                    0-63


[2024-10-07T05:03:32.039111640Z WARN  solana_rpc::rpc_health] health check: behind by 428731 slots: me=293747257, latest cluster=294175988  
[2024-10-07T05:03:32.049978179Z WARN  solana_rpc::rpc_health] health check: behind by 428731 slots: me=293747257, latest cluster=294175988  
[2024-10-07T05:03:32.082574554Z WARN  solana_rpc::rpc_health] health check: behind by 428732 slots: me=293747257, latest cluster=294175989  
[2024-10-07T05:03:50.508462468Z WARN  solana_rpc::rpc_health] health check: behind by 428751 slots: me=293747278, latest cluster=294176029  
[2024-10-07T05:04:06.064856707Z WARN  solana_rpc::rpc_health] health check: behind by 428768 slots: me=293747296, latest cluster=294176064  


You'll need to provide more info, specifically the command used to run the node. It's hard to tell with just this info unfortunately!
